# Optimizing Fading Box Animations

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am trying to build an interactive background for my WPF application. As you can tell from the screenshot below, it consists of individual rectangles scattered throughout the background and I want them to individually fade in and out.

I am calculating the amount of rectangles required based on the Virtual Screen Size of the users machine (mine is 3200x1200 for example). That way maximizing and minimizing the window will reveal more of the background. As stated, for my resolution I am going to need 3220 rectangles.

The way I have this implemented now is all rectangles are added to a canvas with randomly generated alpha values. I then delay-begin an auto-looping animation (see below). Unofrtunatly this is causing my application to be extremely sluggish (rightfully so). Is there anyway I can implement this type of effect and have much better performance?

```
<Storyboard x:Key="uiStoryboardTile" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Transparent"/>
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

[image: Fading Boxes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do to improve performance:

1) Create only the Rectangles that are visible in the background.

2) Randomly bind the Fill property of each Rectangle to one of a number of StaticResources of predefined colors (10-20 should probably do the trick).

3) Create a storyboard that animates those StaticResources.

You would lose the individualality each Rectangle, but it should animate without killing your application.

**EDIT - Code examples**

For example, add some resources to animate (they're rectangles since you can't directly animate a SolidColorBrush):

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Rectangle x:Key="Color0" Fill="#FFFFCFFF" />
        <Rectangle x:Key="Color1" Fill="#FFFFC2C2" />
        <Rectangle x:Key="Color2" Fill="#FFFFEFD2" />
        ...
</Window.Resources>
```

Your Storyboard would look something like:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="BackgroundAnimation" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource Color0}"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                      BeginTime="0:0:0:0"
                                      AutoReverse="True"
                                      Duration="00:00:03.00">
            <ColorKeyFrameCollection>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame Value="Transparent" />
            </ColorKeyFrameCollection>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

     <!-- Add keyframes for each color, varying start and duration -->
      ...
</Storyboard>
```

In your code-behind where you generate all the rectangles, you'll need to bind to the resources.  So somewhere in the loop, you'll need to add:

```
 // I'll leave the implementation of GetRandomColorId to you
 resourceId = GetRandomColorId(MAX_COLORS);

 Shape source = (Shape)this.FindResource("Color" + resourceId);
                    Binding binding = new Binding
                                          {
                                              Path = new PropertyPath("Fill"),
                                              Source = source
                                          };

                    rect.SetBinding(Shape.FillProperty, binding);
```

Finally, all you'll have to do is start the BackgroundAnimation.

Comment: I think you can still animate `Brushes` using `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

a. Don't use so many rectangles.  I know this is obvious, but seriously, three thousand items to animate is A LOT even for a performant machine.

b. Try animating the opacity of the different rectangles instead of the color on the fill brush.  According to my wild ass guess (WAG) theory, this may have a positive effect.

c. Try animating the opacities / colors of each of the rectangles manually instead of using storyboards to tweak the color.  For example:

```
// Disclaimer: This code was written in the SO text editor.  Might not be correct.
foreach (MyRect rect in MyRectangles)
{
  if (rect.FadingIn)
  {
    rect.Opacity += 0.1;
    if (rect.Opacity >= 1) { rect.FadingIn = false; }
  }
  else
  {
    rect.Opacity -= 0.1;
    if (rect.Opacity <= 0 ) { rect.FadingIn = true; }
  }
}
```

You will notice a special class that has a bit of extra information for your needs.

```
class MyRect
{
  public Shape Rectangle;
  public bool FadingIn;

  public double Opacity
  {
    get { return Rectangle.Opacity; }
    set { Rectangle.Opacity = value }
  }

  //... etc.
}
```

Of course there is still some more support code that you will have to put in place, like getting your rectangles to their host, etc. but it sounds like you have already gotten that far on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried animating them in groups?  While you may have 1000+ rectangles perhaps you could break them up in to groups and only have 10 or so animations running at once.  If the blocks are spaced correctly it should still have the appearance of randomly animated rectangles.

This could be done by creating layers of blocks, where each layer is transparent with just it's blocks visible on it.  Stack the layers on top of each other and animate the alpha of each layer.